How to force the argument size for PUSH in MASM 32-bit code?
How do I control the size of the push instruction in MASM 5.0+?
push 42  ; I need this to be 2 bytes: opcode + 1 byte of data.
push 42  ; I need this to be 5 bytes: opcode + 4 bytes of data.

In NASM it's push strict byte 42 and push strict dword 42. I'm looking for the MASM equivalent.

Most other assemblers are not as good as NASM at letting you select an encoding.  I won't be terribly surprised if the answer turns out to be db 68h 2ah 00h 00h 00h.

This seems to work in Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 14.37.32822.0
push byte ptr 42
push word ptr 42
push dword ptr 42
push 42

The opcodes generated are
6a2a            push    2Ah
66682a00        push    2Ah
682a000000      push    2Ah
6a2a            push    2Ah

The stack layout is
000000da`eb36fbf6 000000000000002a 
000000da`eb36fbfe 000000000000002a 
000000da`eb36fc06 00000000002a002a 


Surprised to see that MASM allows such an insane mis-use of ptr when the operand is just an immediate and not a memory reference. As if I needed another reason to dislike MASM...

This seems to work in MASM 5.00 (with a warning), and in MASM 6.00B (without warnings).
